# Websocket Rails Rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a problem to test message triggering from Controller after dispatching an event. Here is my Rspec test:

```
  describe "product.delete" do
    it "should trigger any message" do
      event = create_event("product.delete", :data => "some")
      expect(event.dispatch).to trigger_message :any
    end
  end
```

Here is my Event.rb file where event routing is specified:

```
namespace :product do
    subscribe :delete, :to => ProductController, :with_method => :delete_product
  end
```

Then my Controller code:

```
class ProductController < WebsocketRails::BaseController

  def delete_product
    WebsocketRails[:product].trigger :data => "something"
  end

end
```

And finally here is what I am getting after tests run:

```
    should trigger any message (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) product.delete should trigger any message
     Failure/Error: expect(event.dispatch).to trigger_message :any
       expected product.delete to trigger message with some data, instead it did not trigger any message
     # ./spec/requests/product.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am trying to strictly follow guide on websocket-rails github wiki pages. But definetely there is something I am doing wrong. Can anybody look at my code and advice , please.

Comment: I have found that this is know problem described here with fix proposition which I have successfully applied https://github.com/depili/websocket-rails/commit/5b010567bc13ba759c6945709d84517762b60b6a